# Select Records and Update in One Query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are similar questions asked here, but was not able to find something close enough to actually resolve my problem as they involve multiple tables.  So here goes...

I need to select a recordset for processing.  To prevent parallel processing from selecting the same records, I want to set a status flag in the record that I can use to exclude those records on subsequent calls, i.e.

```
SELECT ... WHERE statusflag <> 1 //(or whatever)
```

I know I could use a transaction and SELECT FOR UPDATE, spinning through those records updating the flag, but I was hoping to accomplish both tasks (get/update) with one database hit.  Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Use `JOIN` and/or subqueries? It really depends on how you want to modify the rows. Also keep in mind that transactions only work with InnoDB tables.

Comment: as far as I know mysql won't allow you to update the table you're selecting from in a single query

Comment: `UPDATE blah SET meh = 'huh?' WHERE (SELECT * FROM my_other_table WHERE something = 47) Something like this? Or are you talking about UPDATE blah SET flag = 0 WHERE statusflag <> 1

Comment: Instead of setting some status flag, could the same process that controls the parallel processing dole-out ranges of the primary key?

Comment: If this is really important to you, you might want to consider switching to PostgreSQL where this kind of thing is really easy (`update foo set statusflag = 1 where statusflag <> 1 returning foo.*`)

Comment: I actually haven't decided what the optimal number of records to process in one query, but it will definitely be at least 250.  I will select the rows, update the status flag, execute the required processing, then update the status flag to complete.  I was trying to shorten the processing and write something more elegant than a while loop.  Thanks for all of the feedback.  PostgreSQL seems like something to look into!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) in a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html). There are a few tutorials on-line that will help you.